# Cannot figure out how to write a complex sql statement in sqlite3

Tags: sql, python-2.7, sqlite

I have 3 tables as follows in my sqlite3 database:

1- List of publications ID, year of publications, Conference it was published in, and number of times it was cited:

```
CREATE TABLE publications (
    ID integer primary key,
    Year integer,
    Conference varchar(150),
    Citations integer
);
```

2- List of references each paper had cited. (This is the list of papers (references) that the publications has cited, as opposed to in the previous paper which states how many times the publication was itself cited by other publications)

```
CREATE TABLE publications_references (
    PaperID integer,
    ReferenceID integer,
    PRIMARY KEY(PaperID, ReferenceID)
);
```

3- Matches each author with it's publication. Many publications have multiple authors, and most authors have multiple publications.

```
CREATE TABLE authors_publications (
    AuthorID integer,   
    PaperID integer,    
    PRIMARY KEY(PaperID, AuthorID)
);
```

This is what I'm trying to do and not succeeding:

- A select statement that gives me the number of citation each author has achieved in each year. To do that I need to do the following:

  1. See if each author has publications listed as references, and categorize them according to years.
  2. Figure out how many times has his work been referenced by others each year, for the years from 1994 till 2013.
- A select statement that gives me the number of citations each conference has achieved in each year. To do that I need to do the following:

  1. See if each conference has publications listed as references, and categorize them according to years.
  2. Figure out how many times the publications for the conference have been references by others in each year, for the years from 1994 till 2013.

I want to end up with a table that looks like this:

1. AuthorID , Year, CitationsforthatYear
2. Conference, Year, CitationsforthatYear

For 2, this is what I have so far:

```
Select Conference, Year, Count(ReferenceID) as CitationsforthatYear
from publications 
join publications_references
on ID=PaperID
group by Conference, Year
```

For some reason it's not working as it should. Maybe I should be using left join?

Comment: Having a column for each year isn't the right way to do it; the columns of a query shouldn't be dynamic.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo can  you propose a better way to do it plz?

Comment: `Author, Year, CitationsForThatYear`

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo any help would be appreciated as I was trying for two days and can't seem to figure it out.